# Unable to set dynamic state from render method react es6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add dynamic states from a method. The idea is when i call the method from a render method it would accept the parameter value to set dynamic state values.

Here is my code:

```
renderFeaturePermissionOptions( featureName ) {
  // Generate permission rules.
  let viewPermission    = featureName + "_view"
  let createPermission  = featureName + "_create"
  let editPermission    = featureName + "_edit"
  let deletePermission  = featureName + "_delete"
  // Set states for all dynamic checkboxes.
  this.setState( { [viewPermission]   : true } )
  this.setState( { [createPermission] : true } )
  this.setState( { [editPermission]   : true } )
  this.setState( { [deletePermission] : true } )
  return(
    <tr>
      <td>{featureName}</td>
      <td><input name={ featureName + "/selectAll" } type="checkbox" onChange={this.checkSiblingCheckBoxes}/></td>
      <td><input name={ featureName + "/view" } type="checkbox"/></td>
      <td><input name={ featureName + "/create" } type="checkbox"/></td>
      <td><input name={ featureName + "/edit" } type="checkbox"/></td>
      <td><input name={ featureName + "/delete" } type="checkbox"/></td>
    </tr>
  )
}
```

I want to refactor this code so that i can call this method for any route name given in the parameter and it will create the states as the parameter name.

Though it is not completed, but when i call this method from the render method like this

```
{ this.renderFeaturePermissionOptions( 'Organization' ) }
```

it takes an infinite loop and generates this error:

[image]

How i can set this states here which are coming from the parameter of `renderFeaturePermissionOptions( 'Contact' )`? -> An example call.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call `setState` in your render function, when you call setState, the component will render again, if you call it in `render` function. it will be endless loop.

so you can try to write it as another childComponent, maybe it can look like this.

```
const trComponent = ({name, onChange}) => {
   return (
        <tr>
          <td>{name}</td>
          <td><input name={ name + "/selectAll" } type="checkbox" onChange={onChange}/></td>
          <td><input name={ name + "/view" } type="checkbox"/></td>
          <td><input name={ name + "/create" } type="checkbox"/></td>
          <td><input name={ name + "/edit" } type="checkbox"/></td>
          <td><input name={ name + "/delete" } type="checkbox"/></td>
        </tr>
   );
}

// if you want to set dynamic state, you can set it in this way
class trComponent extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        let viewPermission    = props.name + "_view"
       let createPermission  = props.name + "_create"
       let editPermission    = props.name + "_edit"
       let deletePermission  = props.name + "_delete"
        this.state = {
            [viewPermission]: true,
            ....
        }
    }

    render () {
        return (
        <tr>
          <td>{name}</td>
          <td><input name={ this.props.name + "/selectAll" } type="checkbox" onChange={this.props.onChange}/></td>
          <td><input name={ this.props.name + "/view" } type="checkbox"/></td>
          <td><input name={ this.props.name + "/create" } type="checkbox"/></td>
          <td><input name={ this.props.name + "/edit" } type="checkbox"/></td>
          <td><input name={ this.props.name + "/delete" } type="checkbox"/></td>
        </tr>
   );
    }
}

// then use it in this way

<trComponent name='Organization' onChange={this. checkSiblingCheckBoxes}/>
```

Comment: I can't understand how the dynamic states are being added here, can u give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You should not set state in render method or methods which are getting called when rendering happens.

This is incorrect in your code.

```
  // Set states for all dynamic checkboxes.
  this.setState( { [viewPermission]   : true } )
  this.setState( { [createPermission] : true } )
  this.setState( { [editPermission]   : true } )
  this.setState( { [deletePermission] : true } )
```

Set state in some lifecycle methods or on some user action on your component.

**Edit:**
Yes initialize your default state in your component's constructor

```
export default class TestComp extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            viewPermission : true,
            createPermission] : true,
            editPermission]   : true,
            deletePermission] : true

        };
    }
 // Rest of your component methods such as render and others
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement this in react?